# Exterior outlet not working

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, circuit-breaker

I have had a problem with 3 rooms and a bathroom all on one breaker. I originally thought I would need to split the circuit, but then decided to check the breaker first in case there were 2 wires connected to the same breaker. A neighbor had an electrician doing some work for him, so I asked the electrician if he would take a look at the breakers in my house when he finished with the neighbor. He came over and sure enough there were 2 wires on the same breaker-a wide breaker that took 2 slots. One black, One red. So, he installed 2 skinny breakers and put the black on one and the red on the other breaker. This seemed to work great and no longer needed to split a circuit. We ran into a problem today: The outside outlet has no power and no breakers were tripped. Is there anything else the Electrician should have done? This is the first time that this outlet has not worked.

Picture of box (bottom left-hand 2 breakers are what's in question here):
[image: picture of panel]

Comment: Check the outlets in the bathroom. A GFCI might have tripped. (Also check all other GFCI outlets you know about.)

Comment: Is the panel a General Electric?

Comment: Yes, the GFCi had tripped. The GFCI and the living room are on the same breaker so when the outlets in the Living room were working I assumed so was the GFCI. I feel stupid for not checking it first

Comment: Yes, you are correct the GFCI in the Bath was tripped. The reason I didn't check it earlier was because all the living room outlets are on that same circuit and they were working fine. I fee so stupid for not checking.

Comment: My knowledge of GE panels is from my old GE one, but I think your original breaker was a single pole (1-pole) 1 inch wide and it was in one full slot *not* two slots. GE panels can take half width breakers and you may now have two 1/2 inch wide breakers in *one* full slot. This is fine but you must use two entirely separate 12-2 or 14-2 cables so the neutrals would not be overloaded.  You could use two 1-pole 1/2" breakers with a 12-3 cable (shared neutral) BUT you must put the two breakers in the bottom half of one slot and the top half of the adjacent slot. Did the electrician do that?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes, he did that. The 2 single breakers are taking up the same space as the 1 fat breaker they replaced.

Comment: @Pat, if you're able to post a picture of your breaker panel with the front cover removed, it will help clear up a lot of questions about what might have happened.

Comment: A picture with the front in place but the door open (showing the breakers) would help. It is not recommended to remove the front unless you are experienced.

Comment: How do I upload a photo? I don't see anywhere to do that.

Comment: @Pat -- you inadvertently tried to edit Robert Moody's answer with your edit attempt.  I grabbed the picture from it and edited into your question for you; next time, edit your question instead of someone's answer if you want to add more things in response to an answer.

Answer (score 4):

The electrician did you no favor . You have a multi fed circuit and the handle ties on the breaker should be together.So both go the same ,and all neutrals should be spliced together to work . Neutral has a load in this case.  And could lead to injury.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the original breaker that was powering these circuits? Does it have two separate connection screws with the black in one and the red in the other or were the black and red in the same connection point secured with the same screw?

The presence of the red wire suggests you have a MWBC with two hots (B & R) and one neutral W. If so, this is supposed to be protected by a 2-pole breaker which may be what you had originally.

**EDIT**
If it is a MWBC, then using two 1-pole breakers could lead to a dangerous condition. If both the red and black wires would be on the same leg of the bus, then the receptacles would appear to be OK, but the neutral could be overloaded. When the two are on different legs (240 V from R to B), then the common neutral would not be overloadable because the net current in the white would be the *difference* in the currents in the R and B wires because they are on different legs. However, if the two 1-pole breakers were put in the same place occupied by the original wider breaker (presumably  a 2-pole breaker), then they would almost certainly be on different legs. If you would find a 240 V difference between the  R and the B hot wires, then they are on different legs and the neutral W would not be overloaded.

But this does not explain why the outside receptacle is not working. I would suspect that a GFCI has tripped or there is a loose connection in some wire heading to the outside receptacle. It could be in the hot path or in the neutral path.

**EDIT2**

My knowledge of GE panels is from my old GE one, but I think your original breaker may have been a single pole (1-pole) 1 inch wide and it was in one full slot not two slots.

GE panels can take half width breakers and you may now have two 1/2 inch wide breakers in one full slot. This is fine but you must use two entirely separate 12-2 or 14-2 cables so the neutrals would not be overloaded.

You could use two 1-pole 1/2" breakers with a 12-3 cable (shared neutral) BUT you must put the two breakers in the bottom half of one slot and the top half of the adjacent slot. Did the electrician do that?

**EDIT3**

Depending on how many open slots you have here is how you would proceed. You use a GE 2-pole compact breaker pair (two 1/2" breakers in one unit) for this pair of circuits.

This 2-pole breaker is mechanically designed so it will *not* snap into a full slot, but will fit in your box only *astride* two slots and it must be put in that way to function properly.

To get space to do this you will probably need to rearrange the breakers and replace one or more full width breakers with 1/2" breakers. It may be that you can use one or both of the 1/2" wide breakers the electrician installed in place of existing 1" wide breakers. But the current limit must be the same as the existing one--don't use a 20 A 1/2" to replace a 15 A 1".

Comment: I have the original breaker and it has only one connection screw. My original problem before having the electrician look at it was a living rm, bath rm., 2 bed rms. and one outlet in the Kit. all on the same breaker. Since he split the 2 wires that were in the original breaker, now I have the Liv rm and Bath Gfci and i kit outlet on 1 breaker and the 2 bd. rms on the other breaker.

Comment: Do you know whether you have two 12-2 + gnd cables or you have one 12-3 + gnd cable? That is, do you know if you have two entirely separate circuits each with its own neutral or you have two circuits sharing a common neutral?

Comment: That, I don't know.

Comment: Do you have a multimeter? Could you send a picture of your panel showing the arrangement of the breakers? Alternatively, could you measure the position of these two new breakers in inches from the top of the first breaker to the bottoms of the 1st new breaker and the 2nd new breaker? Are the two new breakers together in the same place as the original breaker or are they shifted by 1/2 inch? or shifted by 1-1/2 inch?  . . .

Comment: Jim, the 2 new breakers (skinny) take up the same space as the one fat breaker they replaced. They are on the left side (very bottom) of a GE 100 amp box.

Comment: This means these two breakers are on the same leg of the bus. *If* they are *sharing* one neutral, then that neutral may be overloaded. The total current in the two breakers (separate hots R & B) is being carried in the one neutral white wire. That neut will get very hot if the total current is over the limit for the wire you have, *and the breakers will not trip*. The wire would NOT have been getting hot with the old arrangement because the two hots were connected to one breaker. Was the old breaker tripping? Limit the current on these circuits until you get a competent electrician out.

Comment: You *may* be able to shift breakers in the panel to get the two 1/2" breakers on different legs of the bus. Then even if you have only one white (a shared neutral) the wire will not get hot because the currents in the R & B will cancel in the one W. Get a competent electrician to look at the situation. What is the current rating of the original breaker (15 A or 20 A)? What is the current rating of the two new 1/2" breakers?

Comment: The original breaker was 15 A the 2 new ones are both 15A. The 2 new ones are on the bottom left side. I have a 15A fat breaker directly across on the bottom right. It is supposed to operate lights, but I never been able to find the lights it operates. If I were to replace that with a skinny breaker and move one of the breakers on the left to the right, would that work?

Comment: I might be able to puzzle this out, but at this point it would be best for one of the experts to comment. Putting the two breakers across from each other is not standard (it would be hack), and probably the breakers across from each other are on the same leg so it would not accomplish what you want. AFIK they must be side by side and astride two slots as I explained elsewhere. These breakers are not expensive, get a 2-pole 15 A compact breaker pair. This is an urgent matter. You are risking damaged wire and even a house fire.

Comment: Do not use high load appliances (hairdryer, vacuum cleaner . . .) in the bathroom or on either of these two circuits until you get this attended to.